# Export qgis2web map into Paddle website

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, qgis2web

I made a map in QGIS and exported it with the Qgis2web Plugin. I've got a local map with several files. The html index shows me the map as it will be displayed online.

We use [Paddle CMS](https://www.paddle.be/en) to manage our website. In Paddle, it is possible to embed content (with widgets). Therefore, it must be possible to embed the webmap on to the site.

There is a possibility to enter the html-code of the webmap, but I think I will need iframe to get it online. How do I get iframe into the html code of the webmap? Or is there another way to get my map online in a Paddle-widget?

Comment: A platform to build and monitor websites ;)

Comment: https://www.paddle.be/

Answer (score 2):

You have to place the entire folder exported from qgis2web on your web server in a position of your choice and then create a page or widget with iframe type

```
<iframe frameborder = "0" scrolling = "auto" style = "z-index: 10; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; " src = "/website/location_of_your_choice/">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! I'm going to place the entire registry folder on to a hosting platform and try out your line of code! I'll let you guys know if it works!