# Add Leaflet Web Map to Wix Website

Tags: qgis, leaflet, qgis2web

So I have created a Leaflet web map in QGIS with the qgis2web plugin and I was curious if anyone knows how to upload this web map to a wix website? I am asking so I can share the web map with other people by simply sending them a URL link.

Comment: wouldn't the link be the link to the web page?

Comment: did yo try https://support.wix.com/en/article/embedding-custom-code-on-your-site#adding-custom-code-to-your-site

Answer (score 1):

Already answered [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/444175/export-qgis2web-map-into-paddle-website)

You have to place the entire folder exported from qgis2web on your web server in a position of your choice and then send that link to whoever you want or create a page with inside an iframe like this:

```
<iframe frameborder = "0" scrolling = "auto" style = "z-index: 10; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; " src = "/website/location_of_your_choice/">
</iframe>
```